# Gulp: delete generated .png from dest when .svg removed from src

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

I have a Gulp task creating .png fallbacks for .svg files in a src folder:

```
gulp.task('svg2png', ['svg'], function() {
  return gulp.src(src + '/svg/**/*.svg')
  .pipe(plugins.newer(dest + '/svg'))
  .pipe(plugins.svg2png())
  .pipe(gulp.dest(dest + '/svg'))
  .pipe(plugins.notify({
    message: 'svg2png task complete', onLast: true
  }));
});
```

(The `svg` task is svgmin)

I wanted to tidy up behind myself by deleting generated files (in the dest folder) and thought to extend the watch task as below:

```
gulp.task('watch', function () {
  var watchSvg = gulp.watch('src/svg/**/*.svg', ['svg2png']);

  watchSvg.on('change', function(event) {
    if (event.type === 'deleted') {
      var filePathFromSrc = path.relative(path.resolve('src'), event.path);
      var destFilePath = path.resolve('dist', filePathFromSrc);
      del.sync(destFilePath);
    }
  });
});
```

This works in deleting the .svg but what I'd also like to do is delete the matching .png file so there are no orphans. I'm blindly trusting the [Handling the Delete Event on Watch recipe](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/handling-the-delete-event-on-watch.md) so I'm already outside my level of Gulp / JS knowledge to experiment with this modification.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the `.png` file is generated into the same folder as the minified `.svg` file, the following should work:

```
watchSvg.on('change', function(event) {
  if (event.type === 'deleted') {
    var filePathFromSrc = path.relative(path.resolve('src'), event.path);
    var destFilePath = path.resolve('dist', filePathFromSrc);
    del.sync(destFilePath);
    var pngDestFilePath = destFilePath.replace(/.svg$/, '.png');
    del.sync(pngDestFilePath);
  }
});
```